# Schema.xml with multiple schemas (Solr 3.6)

Tags: solr, configuration, schema

I'm setting up **Solr 3.6** on ubuntu, after working on **Bitnami Solr Stack 5.1**.
Here is the situation:

I have different cores in my instance, with a single schema.xml shared.

Basically a schema looks like this :

```xml
<schema name="schema1" version="1.5">
    <fields>
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="item_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <fields>
</schema>
```

So I tried somthing like this :

```xml
<schemas>
  <schema name="schema1" version="1.5">
        <fields>
            <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
            <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field name="item_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <fields>
    </schema>

  <schema name="schema2" version="1.5">
        <fields>
            <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
            <field name="differentField" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field name="anotherDifferentField" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <fields>
    </schema>
</schemas>
```

And then, a

> HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration.
>   occurs.

This error won't happen if I use a single schema in my file.

I know that in a core configuration, a schema name can be applied as an attribute, so it seems logical to be able to have multiple schemas. OR it is just in case I want to not have my schema named **example** ?

Or the solution would be creating a Solr instance for every core (with seems the only option if I can't emcapsulate multiple schemas)

Answer (score 1):

By using **schema** and **schemaName** attributes on my core tag
 from **solr.xml**, I used a different schemas for earch core.

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="." schema="schemaCore1.xml" schemaName="schemaCore1" dataDir="/var/lib/solr/core1/>
    <core name="core2" instanceDir="." schema="schemaCore2.xml" schemaName="schemaCore2" dataDir="/var/lib/solr/core2/>
</cores>
```